# Wrapping the text of a div with a link with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of li that looks something like this:

`<li class="thing">thing</li>`

I want to somehow turn `thing` into `<a href="#" class="remove-thing">thing</a>`

I was messing around with replaceWith but that replacing the whole `li` with an `a` tag instead of just the text. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `wrapInner()` to wrap the inner text of the list item in an anchor :

```
$('.thing').wrapInner('<a href="#" class="remove-thing"></a>');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rdkfk/)